# Google pay, объясните пожалуйста как добавить?

Tags: android, google-pay

Подскажите, пожалуйста, никогда этого не делал, как добавляется в приложение система оплат. Нужно принимать платеж.
Google pay, или какую нибудь другую систему. Не могу с этим разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/overview?hl=ru
Как минимум вот это,а вообще рекомендую использовать платежный агрегатор с api по типу https://wayforpay.com/ru

Comment: Зачем же плодить одинаковые вопросы. Читайте, разбирайтесь, спрашивайте конкретно что не получается. https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/setup?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разобратся именно с GooglePay вам надо это:

https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview

Но можно взять например QIWI-API:

https://github.com/QIWI-API/bill-payments-java-sdk

Comment: Maks, спасибо большое. Хоть кто то что то более подробное  скинул.